# Regex to get the last value

Tags: java, regex

From the following value

`[AAMP-PLAYER]aamp pos: [14..187..202..2196879032]`

I want to get the last number 2196879032

Some times  value will be -1
`[AAMP-PLAYER]aamp pos: [14..187..202..-1]`

Instead of split method how can i extract last digit using regex method

Comment: Psl - If one of the answers resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking it as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 2):

You could match the last (possibly negative) number at the end of the string, just before the closing `]`:

```
(\-?\d+)\]$
```

Answer (score 0):

A number is last if it is not followed (following it anywhere, not just immediately) by any other number.

```
 (\-?\d+)(?!.*\d)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could try using a `String#replaceAll` option here:

```
String input = "[AAMP-PLAYER]aamp pos: [14..187..202..2196879032]";
String num = input.replaceAll("^.*\\.\\.(-?\\d+).*$", "$1");
System.out.println(num);
```

This prints:

```
2196879032
```